# Direct sum of small modules is small, also direct summands of small modules are small.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules, homological-algebra

We say that  $N$ is a **small submodule** of $M$ if whenever $N^{*}$ is a submodule of $M$ such that $N + N^{*} = M$ it yields $M=N^{*}$. If $N$ is a small submodule of $M$, we denote it as $N \leq _{s} M$. I'm struggling proving the following claim:

$S_{1} \leq _{s} M_{1}$  and  $S_{2} \leq_{s} M_{2} $ if and only if   $S_{1} \oplus S_{2} \leq_{s} M_{1} \oplus M_{2}$.

I'm run out of ideas in both implications. I mean, if we assume $S_{1} \leq _{s} M_{1}$ , $S_{2} \leq_{s} M_{2} $ and $S_{1} \oplus S_{2} + N = M_{1} \oplus M_{2}$, I need to show that $N=M_{1} \oplus M_{2} $, so I should find some modules $N_{1} \leq M_{1}$ and $N_{2} \leq M_{2}$ allowing me to properly use my assumption $S_{1} \leq _{s} M_{1}$  and  $S_{2} \leq_{s} M_{2}$ in order  to show that $N=M_{1} \oplus M_{2} $. Likewise, I dont clearly see an optimal way to solve the other implication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is a routine exercise prove these two following properties.

1. If $N_1 \leq_s M$ and $N_2 \leq_s M$, then $N_1+N_2 \leq_s M$.
2. If $N \leq_s M$ and $f \colon M \to L$, then $f[N] \leq_s L$. (The equality $f^{-1}[K+f[N]] = f^{-1}[K]+N$ could be helpful.)

---

Once the above is done, just consider the obvious injections $M_i \to M_1 \oplus M_2$ and the projections $M_1 \oplus M_2 \to M_i$.